# ASP Net MVC pagedlistpager without style

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i installed PagedList.Mvc and PagedList but when i use it i have no style at all:

[Image of pagedListPager without any style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP6l0.png)

My controller looks like that:

```
public ActionResult CarrosList(string search, int? i)
{
    return View(db.Carro.Where(x=>x.Estado != "Vendido" && x.Titulo.StartsWith(search) || search == null).ToList().ToPagedList(i ?? 1, 6));
}
```

And My cshtml page looks like that:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, i => Url.Action("CarrosList", new { i, search = Request.QueryString["search"]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown handles the server side paging and renders the HTML.

**Styles however, are all to do with CSS stylesheets.**

From https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList :

```
<!-- import the included stylesheet for some (very basic) default styling -->
<link href="/Content/PagedList.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Basically make sure the stylesheet is included.

**Gotcha**

Stuff in the Content folder is only installed when you first add the nuget package. So if someone else installed the package and didn't add the relevant CSS file to source control it may be missing. You may need to remove and re-add the nuget package to fix.